# Java Recursion help needed

Tags: java, recursion

I've been asked to create a public method that does nothing but to call another method that is recursive. The purpose of the second method is to search for a `Int` value inside an array.

So far I have this:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 11, 20, 30, 50, 100};
int cont = 0;

public int searchI(int x) {
    searchR(x);
    return x;
}

private void searchR(int y) {
    if (cont < array.length) {
        if (array[cont] == y) {
            System.out.println(y);
        } else {
            searchR(cont++);   
        }
    }
}
```

However, no matter what number I use, either one in the array or not, it always prints the value of `y`. I'm still new to recursion and not quite grasping the essence of it yet. That's probably why my method isn't working (besides that it is wrong). Any thoughts? And probably, help to grasp the term better.

Comment: What you want as output? The position of the searched number?

Comment: I think instead of passing `cont++` you would still need to pass `y`, and increment `cont++` separately, before calling `searchR(y)` in your `else` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far you code, this will print `y` when it finds `y` in the `array` because of

```
if (array[cont] == y) {
     System.out.println(y);
}
```

And after first call of `searchR(x)` it is searching the value of `cont` instead of value of `x`. Change `searchR(cont++)` to

```
cont++; 
searchR(y);
```

If you want the position of the number you're searching use `System.out.println(cont)` instead of `System.out.println(y)`.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 11, 20, 30, 50, 100};
int cont = 0;

public int searchI(int x) {
    searchR(x);
    return x;
}

private void searchR(int y) {
    if (cont < array.length) {
        if (array[cont] == y) {
            System.out.println(y); //System.out.println(cont); if you want the position as output
        } else {
            cont++;
            searchR(y);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i was looking for! It works as it should now.

Comment: @LeinadDC Happy to know that "this is exactly what you were looking for". If so then mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
static final int [] array={1,6,2,7,3,9,5};
 public static void searchI(int x)
{
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(searchR(x,0));
}

   private static int searchR(int x,int _index)
{
    if(_index>array.length)
        return -1;
    else if(array[_index]==x)
        return _index;
    else
        return searchR(x,++_index);
}
```